# Android: Billing 3.0 issues - "Billing unavailable for this package and user"

Tags: java, android, android-billing

I keep getting **"Billing unavailable for this package and user"** and I have set up everything correctly in Google Play Console and have implemented the library as per the docs. Cant find anything on how to overcome this error.

- Test user is logged in and authorized
- License Testing is set to "RESPOND_NORMALLY", with the correct test users
- Followed the docs on how to implement the new billing methods
- Added BILLING permissions to manifest

Anyone know what else to check for this error for billing 3.0?

Comment: You have added the correct email for the tester user in the play console?

Comment: @lolloCreator Yes, test users and licenses are all entered correctly, and I am logged into Google Play on that device with this user.

Comment: I had the same problem but it was solved when Google accepted the upload in alpha mode

Comment: @lolloCreator promoted to Alpha, but still get the same error :/

Answer (score 2):

The Google Play billing service is very picky about how the build is created. You will get mysterious errors if any of these conditions are not satisfied:

- The application ID (package name) must match the one published on the Play Store
- The build must be signed with the Release (not Upload nor Debug) signing key
- The version code of the build must match the version code of a build that is currently active (published) on the Play Store
- The product or subscription item must be Active in the Play Store

Comment: So the package IDs do match and the subscriptions and IAP are active in the Google Play Console. The version code matches that of an internal test build that was promoted to Alpha. As far as the build being signed by release... that doesn't make sense. How do they expect you to TEST before publishing?? Is this new for Billing 3.0 because before that we were able to test and debug without this requirement.

Comment: What about the version of Android? Would this be a compatibility issue? Android Version 9, Security Patch Level Oct 1, 2020.

Comment: So it looks like there is a "Billing" release track. I promoted the build to that track and I am now getting some different logs and no longer see this error, so I believe that's how we must test purchases now, in a "Billing" released track.

Comment: It is cumbersome to test, yes. You can likely get it to work if you sign your local debug builds with the Release key (if you have access to it). I've found the most surprising issue is making sure the version code is active in the Play Store.